# Ruby object declared as constant

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have this piece of Ruby code:

```
HTTPCLIENT = HTTPClient.new

def read_page(url)
  HTTPCLIENT.get(url).body
end
```

The HTTPClient object is being created and declared as a **constant**, and thus it can be accessible by methods.

I would do this by declaring it as a global variable ($) or as a class variable (@), but I'm not sure if it's actually wrong the way it is.

I don't declare objects as variables because, well, their memory contents can vary. I only use constants to declare simple types (strings, numbers) or classes and modules. But objects? I'm not sure about it.

My question is: is this a bad code or it's just me? If so, then why do you think is a bad code?

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose a 3rd way: Make it a method:

```
def client
  @client ||= HTTPClient.new
end

def read_page(url)
  client.get(url).body
end
```

There are some advantages to this:

- You get the same scoping as with a constant (which you wouldn't get with a `$`-global), as well as visibility modifiers.
- It's flexible. You can return anything that fulfils the API contract. It's the Dependency Inversion Principle (the D in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))) of relying on an abstraction. It also allows you to stub/mock the method and return value in tests much more easily.
- If you want it to be shared across instances, use object composition (e.g. `PageReader.new(existing_client)`); if you want different instances to have their own client, use the implementation above.

I'd agree that constants should for be kept "primitive" - or at any rate, they should be data-only. E.g. a `Hash`, while not "primitive" per se, used as constant lookup table is fine. But a HTTP client instance is a bit much.

A 4th option is to make it a singleton, which is more or less a "constant instance". It'd probably require you to wrap (or extend) the `HTTPClient` class, e.g.:

```
require 'singleton'

class Client
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @client = HTTPClient.new
  end

  def get(url)
    @client.get(url)
  end
end

# ...

def read_page(url)
  Client.instance.get(url).body
end
```

Comment: Also consider using `module`, that is already in fact a singleton pattern, not a hack/crutch like `include Singleton`.